# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ncc'

Tags: python, computer-vision, python-packaging

I am trying to install 'ncc' package to use this method (ncc.normxcorr2D) to get correlation results from a template and an image. However, I am getting this error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ncc'
```

even though I installed ncc with this:

```
pip install ncc
```

I think there are some other required packages to successfully install it but I don't know how to check. Would you please help me with this issue.

Thanks

Comment: verify that you use the same python, do "which python" in your terminal

Comment: @Vadim okay then how do I know which other packages to install?

Comment: you don't need other packedge, you need to install it with you current python

Comment: if you use the jupyter notebook, try to install it with it: 
!pip install ncc

Comment: It says, Requirement already satisfied but this error still exists!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a virtual environment , use `conda install -c biobuilds ncclient --user`

[For more information on User Installs](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#user-installs)

Comment: I am using virtual environment. I tried it and I still get this error.

Comment: I think it's a permission problem. What is your OS and are you in a jupyter ntoebook ?

Comment: I am using M1 Mac and a jupyter notebook in virtual environment

Comment: try with `--user`